# Can I add the "nul" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

After working a lot with shell scripts, it turns out that one of the single most important concepts when handling arbitrary user input is the null character, aka. `NUL`, `\0`, `^@`, and others. I added it to a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36233/how-to-skip-file-in-sed-if-it-contains-regex) which included the line

> Is there a way to detect NUL (`\0`) characters in `sed`?

but it was removed by a very high-rated user. Considering how important and difficult NUL handling is in for example Bash, shouldn't it be OK to add this tag (or `null-separator`/`null-character`) to such questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a problem with it. Possibly he removed it because questions can only have five tags, and he thought the tags he was adding were more important than that one

Answer (score 2):

I removed the tag because it didn't seem to address the main points of the question, which were to detect [text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text) files through [shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell) commands, munge line endings ([newlines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newlines)) and do global file processing with [sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sed) — a [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) task.

Furthermore, I'm not convinced of the usefulness of a specific tag for the null byte. Handling it is very closely related with handling [binary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary) data.

Comment: Yeah, I realized the bit about NUL bytes didn't really tie in well with the rest of the question, so I [split it off](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36734/is-there-a-way-to-detect-null-bytes-nul-0-in-sed).